# need method to Send PDF/Image file to user on whatsapp

Tags: python-3.x, whatsapp, document, attachment

I Have been Trying to send the details to user on whatsapp using python pywhatkit module and i have been successful in sending the text data to the Customer but my requirement is to send the PDF File to customer along with text messages.

Text Msg to individual customer

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly("Contact Number", "Text MSG")

Text MSg to Group:

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly("Group ID", "Text MSG")

Method 1:

pywhatkit.sendwhats_image("Group_Name", "Media/image.png", "Hi")

pywhatkit.sendwhats_image("Name", "Media/images.png")

but these methods are unavailable in pywhatkit module.

---

Method 2:

using Twillo or third party but its been expensive or can send registered user.

Any Suggestions regarding the same would be a great help.